# External disk repair error on a MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook, external-hard-drive, troubleshooting

I have my MacBook Pro backed up with Time Machine on a WD external passport drive. Time Machine no longer recognizes the drive and I cannot open any other files that are on it. I tried disk repair, but get the error message "Could not unmount Disk".  Anyone know what this means or what to do next?

Answer (score 1):

Disk Utility can have some problems if the partition is corrupted. [DiskWarrior](http://www.alsoft.com/diskwarrior/index.html) can usually repair any issues with the drive though.